# Firebase Console delete part of Project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-distribution

I am using firebase with my android and iOS app.
My android app got removed from play store once (had to be 18+, it was 16+, don't know why they deleted it, its a joke app and no nudity or brutality is shown :D). Now many users have the old version which will receive no updates anymore. We managed to get many users to change to the new app (uploaded with different package name, everything else is the same)

I want to remove the old version from firebase. It uses old code and will not receive updates.

QUESTION
If I remove the old app from the project, will users still be able to connect to my firebase?
My hope is that they won't be able and will remove the old app (and maybe look up the new one as a reaction)
Will it make anything unexpected? I did not find anything about it despite that I lose the analytics.

As I cannot update the old app there is probably no other way to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to the Realtime Database from an Android or iOS app, all the app needs to know if the URL of that Realtime Database. So no matter if there's an app registration in the Firebase project or not, if the code has the right URL it can connect.

Comment: Great, that's all I wanted to now! Thank you! I hope they will check for updates and then will see that they have to download it again.

Comment: Hey, I have removed the older versions of the app but they are still able to connect to my database and read write to the databank. Isn't that unexpected behavior?

Comment: Sorry, I realize only now what you're asking - and my answer is complete nonsense for that. All that code needs to connect to your Realtime Database is the URL of that database. Sorry about the misfire in my initial answer.

Comment: Oh damn. is there a way to make it impossible for them to connect to the database? As I cannot touch the code of the old apps anymore

Comment: Not currently. There might be something specific to your app that you can do, but that's hard to say for sure.